# PAM pwhistory module is not prompting for choose another password if password has been already used

Tags: password, authentication, pam, passwd

I want set history password reusability limit. I am trying to use pwhistory pam module.

Below is  configuration in ***/etc/pam.d/common-password*** file in Ubuntu (VERSION 20.04.1 LTS)

```
password        requisite      pam_pwhistory.so remember=24
password        [success=1 default=bad]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512 use_authtok
```

Below is output

```
root@localhost:/etc/pam.d# passwd test1
New password:
Retype new password:
Password has been already used.
passwd: password updated successfully
root@localhost:/etc/pam.d#
```

PAM pwhistory module is not prompting for choose another password if password has been already used

How  can I achieve to reject password if its been already used in past?

Answer (score 0):

One thing with editing these files is that pam-auth-update has a tendency to futz with your configs if you make modifications to common-*

Be that as it may, I found that just adding remember=[N]  to the end of pam_unix.so was sufficient. I came here looking for a better answer than that, but this might help someone.

The options in that `[success=1 default=bad]` part choose what command to evaluate next. (either deny or permit). Running pw_history by itself is enough to pester the end user, but not enough to prevent their action from taking place.